# Redundant data in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have two tables viz TblTransactions and TblAdjustments
I want to display all transaction in first (detail-a) and then all adjustments in second (Details B). Upon preview, it shows one transaction and all adjustments, then 2nd transaction and all adjustments, (thus seven transaction with five adjustments show 35 records). How can I overcome this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using sub report in detail b

Answer (score 0):

to my knowledge if there is no sub report then how you are getting detail 2 rows as on set after detail 1?

If you need to get all `TblTransactions` first and all `TblAdjustments` next then take 2 sub reports in 2 detail sections... one for transactions and one for adjustements